# obtain senderID while received message from gcm server

Tags: android

I'm developing push notification using GCM, following [this link](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139).

```
 * */
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(aController == null)
        aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

    Log.d(TAG, "Received message");

    generateNotification(context, message);
}
```

How can I get `senderID` when received message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the link you provided, onMessage method

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(aController == null)
            aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }
```

You could send data such as senderID or other data to be used when you received the message, in the example, price is received

Comment: i need to get info from server? can i get the info direct from gcm

Comment: You could capture the senderID and send it to your webservice, it is more useful as you probably will be sending other data in the future

Comment: can i get something like String senderiD = intent.getExtras().getString("senderID"); and how?

Comment: Yes you can, can you post your webservice code where you send a request to GCM server?

Comment: i'm using exactly the same as the link i just pasted on my question.

Comment: if everything is exactly the same, just substitute the price with your senderID and see if it gets sent over. And from there implement it accordingly